# What does it mean to use "Amazon ES for content recommendations"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-elasticsearch

Looking at the marketing literature for amazon kinesis analytics, I'm looking through their real-time log analytics flow and they have a 4th step where the data is piped to Amazon ES for content suggestions.

[image]

What is Amazon ES?  Is that their elastic search service?  If so, how are personalized recommendations generated from elastic search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you've already realized this by now, but, yes Amazon ES is ElasticSearch, you would need to do the work yourself to pull the elasticsearch data and determine a recommendation.  This marketing material appears to be more for what you can do rather than what it does out of the box.